# Keybord not working properly

Tags: keyboard, bug-reporting

I have an issue with my French keyboard for over a year and the issue was not solved yet:

My laptop is a Sony `SVS1311F3EW`. The `Fn` key and some other keys like "z", ")" or "6" are not working at all. The input source to use is set to `French`. I am using the `system keyboard layout` in `ibus-setup` configuration. When i try to reconfigure it using the command line `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, the computer brand "Sony" is not listed at all. Do you have any suggestions to help me get back my keyboard?. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry this is a complex question since it involves a keyboard I don't have for a language I don't speak. Hope someone can answer your question but it's pretty hairy. I would suggest we first find out what file is being used for mappings currently. Also, what happens if you use a US layout does the Fn key in question work? If so we can combine the two

Comment: I am currently using English layout. I am using another keyboard (QWERTY) plugged at my laptop. In both keyboards the `Fn` key is not working.

Comment: Does it ever work with just a single keyboard?

Comment: My laptop's keyboard is not working properly with both English and French input sources.

Comment: It seems that my problem has been solved by Ubuntu. Thank you!